# how many character can set for string variable?

Tags: c#, string, variables

I have a variable with string type. For example `string test;`.

How many character i can set for  test? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The maximum size of all reference type (like a string) instances is limited
by the CLR to 2GB. Since a character in .NET takes 2 bytes, that means a string can hold a maximum of around 1 billion characters.

Note that .NET strings aren't really designed for these sizes. They are immutable and all string operations create new string instances. When you have data this large, you need to custom-design your algorithms and in-memory (and probably on-disk, for really huge data) structures around what you want to do with it.

Comment: Can you further explain why a 2GB limit on the CLR equates to "1G characters"?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Keep in mind that each character takes 2 bytes in .NET.

Comment: i can't set 11 million character in string variable?is it true ok?